# Remove action from plugin

Tags: actions

I'm trying to remove an action in **edit_user_profile** from a plugin. But I don't know how to do, This is add_action from the plugin : https://github.com/jaredatch/Basic-User-Avatars/blob/master/init.php

```
/**
 * Initialize all the things
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function __construct() {
    // Text domain
    $this->load_textdomain();
    // Actions
    add_action( 'admin_init',                array( $this, 'admin_init'               )        );
    add_action( 'show_user_profile',         array( $this, 'edit_user_profile'        )        );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile',         array( $this, 'edit_user_profile'        )        );
    add_action( 'personal_options_update',   array( $this, 'edit_user_profile_update' )        );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update',  array( $this, 'edit_user_profile_update' )        );
    add_action( 'bbp_user_edit_after_about', array( $this, 'bbpress_user_profile'     )        );
    // Shortcode
    add_shortcode( 'basic-user-avatars',     array( $this, 'shortcode'                )        );
    // Filters
    add_filter( 'get_avatar',                array( $this, 'get_avatar'               ), 10, 5 );
    add_filter( 'avatar_defaults',           array( $this, 'avatar_defaults'          )        );
}
/**
 * Loads the plugin language files.
 *
 * @since 1.0.1
 */
public function load_textdomain() {
    $domain = 'basic-user-avatars';
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), $domain );
    load_textdomain( $domain, WP_LANG_DIR . '/' . $domain . '/' . $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo' );
    load_plugin_textdomain( $domain, false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() {
    global $basic_user_avatars;
    remove_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( &$basic_user_avatars, 'edit_user_profile' ) );
});
```

You need to make sure this is done *after* the other plugin has been initialized, therefore the `plugins_loaded` action.

Comment: Thanks Mickael ! Sadly this does not seem to work. I added "9999" to the priority ? Is it good or I misunterstand something ? Have a nice day

Comment: The priority must be the same as in the corresponding `add_action`. To make sure your code gets executed at a later point, you could wrap it into a `plugins_loaded` action. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Mickael, I understand better. How can I run some tests to determinate what is wrong ? Thank you

Comment: This should work, but you didn't say where - in which file - you are running the code to remove the action.

Comment: In functions.php of my child theme.

Comment: I updated my answer with using the '&' operator for the class instance. I'm using this in one of my own plugins, so hopefully that makes it work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83220/discussion-between-garrosh-and-michael).